# Optimizing my insertion to SQL table while parsing through a long list of string

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing

I am not sure if the way I'm inserting to values while I parse is the most efficient way of doing this. I am splitting the logic where each info will be stored based upon whether it's a string or int value. The each info's ID will be stored in Info table where ID is the ID and InfoDescription is the name.

```
ID  Name         DataType
1   weight        int
2   price         int
3   avilability  string

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Info](
    [InfoID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [InfoDescription] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

so weight will have INfoID of 1 and InfoDescription of "weight"

I am going to insert values into this table while I parse through a string.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[fruitLog]
(
    [LogID] [bigint]        NOT NULL,//auto increment maybe
    [InfoID]                [smallint]      NOT NULL,
    [InfoInt]               [bigint]        NOT NULL,
    [InfoString]            [varchar](100)  NOT NULL,
)
```

For example something like "weight:50, price:10, avilability: yes"

-weight will have InfoID = 1, InfoInt=50(0 is default), InfoString=""(since weight is a type of int and not a string) for fruitLog

-avilability will have InfoID = 3, InfoInt=0 (0 is default), InfoString="yes" for fruitLog

This is the logic of my code:

```
//making a key value pair for the Info table so if I have a key of "Weight", I have it's value as 1(ID).
Dictionary<string,int> MsgList = new Dictionary<string,int>();
var list = result from "SELECT * FROM Info"//didn't want to write the whole code out 
foreach(var item in list)
{
    MsgList.Add(item.InfoDescription, item.InfoID);
}

foreach(var fruits in listOfFruits)
{
    get.InfoCOMMAND();// will return something like {weight:50, price:10, avilability: yes}

    //loop through the Info text and parse        
    {
        if (parsedVariable.Equals("weight"))
        {
            InertIntoSQL( MsgList["weight"] , Convert.ToInt32(parsedVariable.value),"");
        }
        if (parsedVariable.Equals("price"))
        {
            InertIntoSQL( MsgList["price"] ,  Convert.ToInt32(parsedVariable.value, "");
        }
        if (parsedVariable.Equals("avilability"))
        {
            InertIntoSQL( MsgList["avilability"] ,  0 , parsedVariable.value.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

InertIntoSQL will be a method that will insert those variables to the table.\

I'm going to have over 30 columns for the diagnostic log so I was wondering if there was an more efficient way of doing this. Also if you know the best way to parse through the string let me know. Thank you.

Comment: If all you're doing is moving data between tables, why make the round-trip through your C# code at all? Do it via a query, with your logic in the SQL. It will be *much* faster to do this as one set-based operation than looping through another program that's making round-trips to the database for each record.

Comment: Unrelated, but are you sure you need `bigint` as your key?  Do you expect to have more than 2 billion rows?  [SQL Server Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)

Comment: When storing data into SQL you can't stgore one value at a time.  Each Insert will go into a different row.  So you end up with a zig-zag array.

Comment: @alroc I'm not sure what you mean, sry I'm new. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly.  I have a list of fruits and for each fruit I have an Info command I can get for each fruit. I need to parse the info and store it in the table. I should have named the table and the command name different.

Comment: @jdweng actually that is what I want. Each will have its own row. each InfoID will have it's own row.

Comment: Does it make sense to store a price without the item name?  How do you know if the $1.00 item was a grape. banana, or water melon?

Comment: @jdweng ah, I forgot to add the fruitName for the fruitLog table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the SqlBulkCopy.  I had to use it a little bit ago to populate a bunch of data into SQL for analysis purposes - here's what my function looked like:

```
private void PopulateTable(DataTable data, string tableName)
{

    string connectionString = @"Server=PC40808\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Scratchpad;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
        copy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        copy.WriteToServer(data);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

... basically, you create a DataTable that matches your SQL table.  Populate the rows of your DataTable - and then, finally, you submit the DataTable to SQL via SqlBulkCopy (all part of the System.Data.SqlClient library.)

Anyway, if it helps, here's my function that creates a blank DataTable for my particular case:

```
private DataTable GetBlankDTForRetrievals()
{
    DataTable retVal = new DataTable("retrievals");
    retVal.Columns.Add("ObjectID", typeof(string));
    retVal.Columns.Add("DateTimeStamp", typeof(string));
    retVal.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    retVal.Columns.Add("DocClass", typeof(string));
    retVal.Columns.Add("Func", typeof(string));
    return retVal;
}
```

... as well as a function that populated my DataTable:

```
private DataTable GetDataTableForSingleRetrievalFile(string fileLoc)
{
    DataTable retVal = GetBlankDTForRetrievals();
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileLoc);
    foreach(string line in lines.Where(l => l.Length > 94).Where((l) => l.StartsWith(" ")))
    {
        DataRow rowToAdd = retVal.NewRow();
        rowToAdd["ObjectID"] = line.Substring(48, 15);
        rowToAdd["DateTimeStamp"] = line.Substring(1, 17);
        rowToAdd["Username"] = line.Substring(32, 15);
        rowToAdd["DocClass"] = line.Substring(69, 20);
        rowToAdd["Func"] = line.Substring(90, 4);
        retVal.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```